# Django error with ForeignKey reference

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, admin

I have a question about a ForeignKey reference problem with django.

This is a part of my code :

App ticketsTrader

```
class TicketsTrader(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='ticketsTrader_seller')
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='ticketsTrader_buyer')
    inscription = models.ForeignKey(Inscription)
    transactionCode = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=False,null=False)
    ...
```

App inscription

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    description = models.TextField()
    ...

class Inscription(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    packs = models.ManyToManyField(PackChoise)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.event.__unicode__() + u': ' + self.user.__unicode__()

    def inscriptionKey(self):
        return str(self.pk) + '_' + str(self.valkey)
```

But when I try to acces to the "Add Ticket Trader" interface in my Grapelli admin, I get an error message :

> User matching query does not exist.
>
> Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in get, line 366
>
> In template \grappelli\templates\admin\includes\fieldset.html, error
>   at line 19

What I want to get is : in the "inscription" column of my ticketTrader table get the value of the unique id (pk) of my "Inscription" table.

Or the value of the "inscriptionKey" but I don't think it's possible.

Django Version:1.4 / Python Version: 2.7.3 / South last version

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You have `buyer = models.Field(...)`. This should be `ForeignKey(...)`. I guess this is not in your actual model.py code?

Comment: Oh sorry this is an error of copy past form my code to here beacause I was trying something. I correct it thanks :). But it's not the part who make the problem. But witout this mistake, yeah it is my actual model.py.

Comment: Argh, please fix your `__unicode__` method. Never call another object's magic functions directly - use the built-in `unicode()` function instead. Anyway, your method should just be `return u'%s: %s' % (self.event, self.user)`.

Comment: Well thanks for the tip Daniel :) I'll check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess:

TicketsTrader has a foreign key to Inscription, which has a foreign key to User and uses that key in its `__unicode__()` method.

Now, I don't know Grapelli but the default admin app would render a dropdown for Inscription-s on the Add TicketsTrader page. If some of the `Inscription`-s pointed to non-existing `User`-s, then their `__unicode__()` method would fail with the error message you specified.

The question is how could some `User`-s be missing and `Inscription`-s pointing to them not. Well, if you use e.g. MySQL+MyISAM, foreign keys are not enforced there so all sorts of weird things can happen.

Comment: Well we are using MySQL+MyISAM.
I've checked the integrity of our database and one inscription was with no user, we are migrating to a new website and it's because the migration script was failing on this user because he had a strange/special char username that will not be allowed in the new one. Thanks a lot or your help. I was searchning too far :D

Comment: @yann: you might consider using InnoDB. And if you need full-text search then either use InnoDB + (Sphinx|Xapian|...) or switch to PostgreSQL (which is a more complete database than MySQL anyway).

Comment: I'm not the one who choosed the database type, but I'll check with him. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you don't have any User... try create User before create Ticket Trader

Comment: There was users, but as said in the precedent post, there was an inscription without user and this create a database corruption. But thanks.